# Troubleshooting 'Bad Request' Error When Using Mappable Geocoder API

Tags: postman

Recently i've started to work with mappable's geocoder. I have a problem with searching objects in a specified area.

Request from example:

https://geocoder.api.mappable.world/v1/?apikey=%API%&geocode=Dubai+Marina&ll=25.080549,55.136670&spn=3.552069,2.400552&lang=en_US

works fine. But when i change it to my request, i got error 400.

I use Postman and here is my request:

> [https://geocoder.api.mappable.world/v1/?apikey={{APIKEY}}&&geocode=Le](https://geocoder.api.mappable.world/v1/?apikey=%7B%7BAPIKEY%7D%7D&&geocode=Le)
> Royal&ll=49.612214;6.124696&spn=3.552069,2.400552&lang=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Use dothttp

```http
GET https://geocoder.api.mappable.world/v1/
? "apikey" = '{{API}}'
? "geocode" = 'Dubai Marina'
? "ll" = '25.080549,55.136670'
? "spn" = '3.552069,2.400552'
? "lang" = 'en_US'
```

And in properties section
API=""

For more information https://docs.dothttp.dev/docs/variables